# How to remove the space in an item, due to starting with a \marginpar?

Tags: spacing, marginpar

The following picture (MWE follows below) demonstrates the problem. There is a space at the beginning of the list when it begins with a \marginpar. I appreciate that something must be on the line directly after the \item so I tried \mbox and a zero width \makebox, but this didn't help.

[image: picture of MWE]

My original intention was to ask with \reversemarginpar but I noticed the same affect happens with simply \marginpar.

%%%%%%%%%%%% MWE %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Some text to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the fron or not.

\item \mbox{}\marginpar{(A space)} Some text to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the fron or not.

\item \makebox[0pt][l]{}\marginpar{(A space)} Some text to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the fron or not.

\item Some text \marginpar{(OK, but not nice code)} to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the fron or not.

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not specific to `\marginpar` either - it's just they way that TeX works. In 2 and 3, you start the text after `\item` with an `\mbox` which is a "thing" - even though it's an invisible thing with zero width. If you follow that by white space, big surprise, - LaTeX actually typesets that white space! On the other hand in 4, `\marginpar` doesn't typeset anything in the main output (it just puts a box in the margin) so the string of whitespace characters (one before it, one after) is merged into a single space when it is typeset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

i would redefine `marginpar` and then not care for spaces after its use:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{marginnote} % not needed
\let\oldmarginpar\marginpar
    \renewcommand{\marginpar}[1]{%
        \leavevmode%
        \oldmarginpar{#1}%
        \ignorespacesafterend\ignorespaces%
                              }

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Some text to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the front or not.

\item \marginpar{(A space)}Some text to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the front or not.

\item \marginpar{(A space)} Some text to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the front or not.

\item \marginpar{(OK, but not nice code)}    to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the front or not.

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get lost of that space, by leaving out that space after the argument of `\marginnote` (`\marginnote{margin stuff}Other text`). So your MWE should look like:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{marginnote}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}

\item Some text to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the fron or not.

\item \mbox{}\marginpar{(A space)}Some text to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the fron or not.

\item \makebox[0pt][l]{}\marginpar{(A space)}Some text to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the fron or not.

\item Some text \marginpar{(OK, but not nice code)}to see what happens when we get to a second line and if there is a space at the fron or not.

\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: IMO this is a better answer. Redefining `\makepar` is trying to make TeX work a different way from how Knuth designed it. Even if you succeed for one command, there will be another, and another, and another - and then your redefinitions might start interacting with each other ... ! Much better just to learn how to use it the way it was intended to be used, and don't put a space in the input where you don't want one in the output.

Comment: @alephzero totally agreed. Learning how to use correct syntax is the preferable way here, because the same issue could arise from almost every macro taking one or more arguments...